# How to have a combined toolbar with views from activity and fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-toolbar, searchview

I have an activity in which I have added a Navigation Drawer with a custom Toolbar. This my **activity** layout:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </LinearLayout>

    //NavigationView
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In the activity I have also added a custom menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/sign_out"
        android:title="Sign-out"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

In this moment I have the burger icon and the three dots, which is what I want.

[image]

The problem arrives I try to add a search functionality in the fragment. This is how my **fragment** layout file looks like:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Instead of adding the SearchView to the actual Toolbar it creates another one. So I get two Toolbars. The problem is that I don't want to inflate the SerachView via a menu file in the fragment, I need to have it my layout file. How to have a single ToolBar that contains all three views (burger icon, the three dots and SearchView)?

This is what I have:

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

**SOLVED:**

I solved this by removing the Toolbar from the activity and set separate toolbar in each fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the below approach to achieve it:

1. Keep the Search item as always hidden in menu.xml

(In your activity)

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.<your menu name>, menu)

    menu?.findItem(R.id.<search item id>)?.isVisible = false

    val visibleFragment = supportFragmentManager.getCurrentNavigationFragment() //This is an extension function, which will return the current visible fragment
    visibleFragment?.let {
        if (it is SearchFragment) {
            menu?.findItem((R.id.search))?.isVisible = true
        }
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

Refer menu.xml for full code

2. Change the visibility of the "search item" when your "SearchFragment" is visible. This can be achieved by using the listener approach. When the SearchFragment is visible send a callback to activity and call "**invalidateOptionsMenu()**"
3. To get the current visible fragment in Navigation graph, you can create an extension function as below:

   fun FragmentManager.getCurrentNavigationFragment(): Fragment? =
       primaryNavigationFragment?.childFragmentManager?.fragments?.first()
4. In your SearchFragment, initialize the listener in onAttach method.
5. Send action to MainActivity by using listener fron onViewCreated.

I have pushed the full code on Github for your reference.
***https://github.com/parmeshtoyou/StackOverFlowActionBar***

[Updated action bar in Search Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx1gE.png)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Vote-up for your idea. I just solved it as in my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

In your `menu` add the search item as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/sign_out"
        android:title="Sign-out"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/search_label"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />

</menu>
```

Then edit your `onCreateOptionsMenu` as follows to add the search item (kotlin code):

```
        val menuInflater = menuInflater
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.<your_toolbar_menu_name>, menu)

        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)

        val searchManager =
            this@YourActivityName.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager

        var searchView: SearchView? = null
        if (searchItem != null) {
            searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
        }
        searchView?.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(this@YourActivityName.componentName))
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
```

I guess that you want this search to only appear when your Fragment is visible. To do that you should check if the fragment is visible or only run above code when the fragment transaction is done. Do ask if anything is not particularly clear.

Comment: So you say that I should display the SearchView according to the fragment that is selected?

Comment: I do not know your exact implementations, but I think that you maybe want to display search only when there's a particular fragment on the activity. 
If that is your case, you can check for that in `onCreateOptionsMenu` and then only inflate the Search Menu item.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Vote-up for your idea. I just solved it as in my updated question.

Comment: @Jorn I am glad , this was of help to you